# need jQuery plugin for making items in textbox (like outlook)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, textbox, richtextbox

i was wondering is exist a jQuery plugin for making items in intput text. I mean for example if you write message in Outlook and in recipients line you enter 2 contacs - when you pres backspace you delete whole email address. Not only first word like in normal textbox.

It there any solution to do this in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you could probably accomplish this functionality by handling keydown event on the input text.  If it's backspace, grab the value, parse it, remove the set of characters that needs to be removed, and set the value of the input to whatever you have left.

The only thing is, you would probably need to watch for where the cursor is inside the input text.